# Tips to know what to condition on in probability: Win by Two

Tags: probability

Calvin and Hobbes play a match consisting of a series of games, where Calvin has
probability p of winning each game (independently). They play with a “win by two”
rule: the first player to win two games more than his opponent wins the match. Find
the probability that Calvin wins the match (in terms of p) by conditioning.

$W$ = "Calvin wins by 2 by moving from $k$ to $k+2$",
$"G_1 = C"$ is "Calvin won game 1"

Anyways, we have

$P(W) = P(W|G_1 = C)P(G_1=C) + P(W|G_1=H)P(G_1=H) = p^2 + qP(W|G_1=H) = p^2+q(p*P(W) + P(W) * p)$

When we solve for $P(W)$ we get $P(W) = p^2/1-2qp$

This is right, but I wonder if $P(W|G_1=H) = p*P(W) + P(W)*p$ is a weird way to think of the problem. Basically $P(W)$ is the probability of moving to the right by 2, and so if we're at $i-1$ and want to get to $i + 2$, we can either move to right by 1 then 2 ($p*P(W)$), or 2 then 1 ($P(W)*p$). Is this a weird/wrong way of thinking of it?

By the way, I am aware of the method of conditioning on the outcomes of the first 2 games. But I wouldn't have thought of this way of conditioning without looking at the solution. Are there any tips regarding what I should condition on?

Comment: To me, the natural thing here is to work by states.  Paths are no good  as the players can endlessly rock back and forth.  But it's a Markov process, all that matters is where the players wound up on the last round.  So, I'd have active states $\{-1,0,1\}$ according to how many games Calvin is ahead, with a Loss state at $-2$ and a Win state at $2$.  Transitions are obvious.  Similar to conditioning, but a fairly general approach, at least to Markov problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $l$ be the state where $C$ is **l**evel with $H$,
$a$ be the state where $C$ is $1$ **a**head of $H$
and $b$ be the state where $C$ is $1$ **b**ehind $H$

At start, we are in state $l$, and we want the $Pr$ that $C$ ultimately wins from start, so we get the following equations:

$l=p*a +(1-p)*b\;\;$[From level, $C$ gets $1$ ahead or $1$ behind]

$a =p +(1-p)*l\;\;$[From $1$ ahead, $C$ wins or drops down to level]

$b=p*l\;\;$[From $1$ behind, $C$ must climb back to level for win]

Solving, we get P($C$ wins) = $\dfrac{p^2}{2p^2-2p+1}$

---

**Alternate method**

With $C's$ win/lose probabilities of $p$ and $q$ for any game,$\;(q=1-p)$

Suppose P(C ultimately wins) $= w$, then
either C wins in two games, with $Pr=p^2$,
or returns to square one (restart) with $Pr=pq+qp = 2pq$

Thus $w = p^2 +2pq\cdot w$, which yields

$w = \dfrac{p^2}{1-2pq} = \dfrac{p^2}{2p^2-2p+1}$